# Scalar curvature in terms of second fundamental form, reference request

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I would like to cite a reference for the following formula for scalar curvature:

> If $\Sigma$ is a hypersurface in Euclidean space, then $R=H^2-\lvert A\rvert^2$, where $R$ is the scalar curvature of
>   $\Sigma$, $A$ is the second fundamental form of $\Sigma$, and
>   $H=-\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}A$ is the mean curvature of $\Sigma$.

This formula is a special case of a more general formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations#Mean_curvature) where $\Sigma$ is a hypersurface in a manifold rather than Euclidean space. It can be quickly proved from the Gauss equation or by computing both sides in terms of the principal curvatures, but I was unable to find it in the textbooks I checked. Would you happen to recognize this formula and be able to suggest a citation for it?

Comment: I would call it a special case of the Gauss-Codazzi equations. It is classical and you can find it on any textbook in Riemanniana Geometry, such as do Carmo, Petersen, Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine, ...

Comment: It's a formula that appears in any paper studying or using the scalar curvature of a hypersurface. Since most textbooks don't discuss specifically results involving the scalar curvature of a hypersurface, they probably don't mention this formula. However, as you say, it's derived easily by simply taking two traces of the Gauss equations. So, if you want to cite it, just say something roughly like that. Or you could google for papers about it and look for one that states the formula explicitly.